# Solve equations with Monte Carlo

Tags: equation-solving

I am dealing with a complicated problem. I will use a simple problem to explain it.

I have two variables x and y, and two equations:

x+y=A

2x+y=B

The value of A and B is determined by measurement, for example, A=2+-0.2, B=3+-0.3. +- 0.1, and +-0.2 is the error of the measurement. For this simple problem, the solution of x,y with error can be solved by some other methods. One method is Monte Carlo. Try the possible solution of (x,y), and test it whether satisfy 1.8

For example, try

x=0,1,2,3;

y=0,1,2,3;

Then we can find x=1 and y=1 is one possible solution. Then we can reduce the range of x,y,to [0,2] and x=1+-1,and y=1+-1.

Repeat this process.

x=0,0.5,1.0,1.5,2.0

y=0,0.5,1.0,1.5,2.0

Then (x,y)=(1.0,1.0) again, but this time we will find x=1.0+-0.5, y=1.0+-0.5.

Finally, we can find the solution is x=1.0+-0.1, y=1.0+-0.1.

My question is how to write the code in Mathematica.

Comment: Why not simply use `Solve` on your simultaneous equations?  It works perfectly.

Comment: First, the real problem has 10 variables and the equations are too complicated to use Solve. Secondly, I also need to know the error of the result, it seems Solve cannot do this.

Comment: One approach would be to restate your problem as an optimization problem and to then use NMinimize. Observe that in the Method option for NMinimize is the option "Randomsearch" which is a kind of Monte Carlo method.

Comment: You can get outer bounds on the solution set using intervals. `In[472]:= aa = 2 + Interval[{-.2, .2}];
bb = 3 + Interval[{-.1, .1}];
Solve[{x + y == aa, 2*x + y == bb}, {x, y}]

Out[474]= {{x -> Interval[{0.7, 1.3}], y -> Interval[{0.5, 1.5}]}}`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP, showing little effort of his own, is simply begging others to write code for him